# How to make snaps see the real /tmp?

Tags: snap, tmp, restricted-access

I'm again and again getting annoyed by the fact that snaps don't see the "real" `/tmp`.

One example why this is bad is that I'm unable to use "Open with -> Xournalpp" with PDFs from email attachments in Thunderbird because they are stored in the real `/tmp` for this.

Is there any way (however hacky it may be) to change this so that every snap can access `/tmp`?

Comment: This affects VLC and Thunderbird integration in Ubuntu 20.04.

I simply installed synaptic package manager and re-installed both using distro-maintained debian packages from Ubuntu (may have been universe or whatever third-party repo as I activate them all).

Comment: Or you can use the PPA instead. https://xournalpp.github.io/installation/linux/

Answer (score 2):

If a snap is called `mysnap`, then by default (with *strict* confinement) it has a private */tmp*, which is `/tmp/snap.mysnap/`. Having a private */tmp* is good for security.

If you are creating a snap package, you can apply either the *classic* or *devmode* confinement, and it will be able to see the system-wide `/tmp`.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, I don't care where the fake snap-tmp is. Neither am I going to create a snap package. But maybe there's an answer lurking around here. Is it possible to un-snap, for example, pdftk, make it 'devmode', and then install it? Might this even be scriptable? That would be great!

Comment: You asked a generic question and received a generic answer. Now you mention that the package is `pdftk`. You can find their repository, clone it, then use `snapcraft` to create your own snap package. They have instructions of that.

Comment: The answer is generic, but doesn't fit to the question. pdftk is just an example, I'm looking for a way to get every snap see the real tmp. The next example I'm struggling with is xournalpp. I'm not going to rebuild every snap to make it useful.

Comment: @Jasper You can install any snap with `--classic` or `--devmode`-option, just take a look at `man snap`. No reason to rebuild a snap. I can't say which mode is sufficient for you, I never had a reason to try it.

Comment: Thanks @mook765, but that doesn't seem to help. I just did that and still get `/usr/bin/env: ‘/tmp/mozilla_j0/xxx.pdf’: Permission denied`.

Comment: Sorry the symbolic link approach I suggested indeed did not work - now I tested it myself. Likely, a mount bind of /tmp into a subfolder of a folder where the snap has permissions (e.g. Documents in case of Xournalpp) would work. Indeed, this confinement cripples the possibility to quickly open files from a browser or email client that exist in .tmp.